# Display multiple data using php

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT count(floor_hall.o_id) as count, office_hall.*,floor_hall.* 
            FROM 
`floor_hall` 
            INNER JOIN office_hall on office_hall.o_id=floor_hall.o_id 

            group by floor_hall.o_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    
    $rows=array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        $rows[] = $row;
    
    // Fetch and display the results
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $id = $row['office_name'];
        $count = $row['count'];
        $fname = $row['f_name'];
        
        echo "Area: $id, Count: $count, <br>$fname <br>";
    }
    
    ?>
```

i tried using this one and it only show this one

[image]

how would i get this data

```
Area: Nex Tower, Count: 1,
20th floor

Area: Nex54, Count: 3,
10th floor
11th floor
12th floor
```

floor_hall
[image]
office_hall
[image]
this is the sample of my databaase

Comment: Which table does each value in your desired result come from? Don't use `SELECT *` when you only need specific columns, select just the columns you're using.

Comment: Don't forget we can't see your source data. Its difficult to write queries for data you can't see. So if you want our help, please show sample data. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to combine values from all the results in a group. Then use `explode()` in PHP to separate them so you can show them on a different line.

Since you didn't post the table schemas, I'm making some assumptions below.

```
$query = 'SELECT o.office_name, COUNT(*) AS count, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(f.f_name ORDER BY f.f_id) AS names, 
                GROUP_CONCAt(f.f_id ORDER BY f.f_id) AS floor_ids
          FROM floor_hall AS f
          JOIN office_hall AS o ON f.o_id = o.o_id
          GROUP BY f.o_id';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['office_name'];
    $count = $row['count'];
    echo "Area: $id, Count: $count, <br>";
    $floors = explode(',', $row['names');
    $floor_ids = explode(',', $row['floor_ids']);
    foreach ($floors AS $i=> $fname) {
        echo "{$floor_ids[$i]}: $fname<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you this is working for me i love you hehehe

Comment: i have question i want to get the the ID of the floors how do i do it @Barmar

Comment: because by using this it only combine it in one tables but i need to get the id of the f_id so that i can use it on other process

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get the floor IDs as well. I've added that to the answer.